# Set inputpanel location on WindowsCE

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, compact-framework, windows-ce

Maybe it isn't possible, but could I set the location of an inputpanel?

I tried `inputpanel.Bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)` but the inputpanel is reading only.

I don't want to re-size the inputpanel, just set its location.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason (known only to the team who created it) the [InputPanel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel_members%28v=vs.90%29) doesn't expose everything that an actual SIP (soft input panel) supports.  In this case, docking.  Generally speaking, a SIP can be set to "floating" (the `SIPF_DOCKED` bit of the [`SIPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499105%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) turned off) and then it can be moved.  You can use P/Invoke [`SipSetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee505516%28v=winembedded.60%29) to set the `SIPINFO` to both turn off the `SIPF_DOCKED` bit as well as set the SIP's new position.